# Choose audio stream in Media Element

Tags: c#, wpf, stream, mediaelement, video-player

We're creating a video player in WPF using .NET 4.0. For this purpose we are using `MediaElement`. For videos with multiple audio streams, we have `MediaElement.AudioStreamIndex` property in Silverlight and Windows Store apps. But I didn't find any similar property in WPF. Am I missing something? What's the best way to implement such functionality in WPF?

Comment: The alternative is to user VideoLan DotNet for WPF as explained in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24466439/2550529