# Change Audio Stream in VideoLan DotNet for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, libvlc

We're using [VideoLan DotNet for WPF](http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/) to play DVD movies in our WPF application. Some movies have multiple audio stream. (for example in multiple languages) How can we choose the desired audio stream?
While searching [VideoLan's Wiki](https://wiki.videolan.org/VlcUserControl.cs/), I found this:

```
[Browsable(false)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        public int AudioTrack
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nativeVlc.GetVlcObjectInt(ObjectType.VLC_OBJECT_INPUT, "audio-es", -1);
            }
            set
            {
                this.nativeVlc.SetVlcObjectInt(ObjectType.VLC_OBJECT_INPUT, "audio-es", value);
            }
        }
```

But I can't find the same property in the project I'm using (Vlc.DotNet)
So how can I detect how many audio streams exist and choose one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do so (mediaPlayer is an instance of `VlcControl`):
We can count audio streams using `mediaPlayer.AudioProperties.TrackCount` and select the index using `mediaPlayer.AudioProperties.Track`.
Now is there any way to get their description? (They usually have a name such as "English")

Answer (score 0):

i'm using VLC control in Windows form and my code for work

```
private void karaokeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             // MessageBox.Show(axVLCPlugin21.audio.count.ToString(), "audio track");
            if (axVLCPlugin21.audio.track == 1)
            {
                try
                {
                    axVLCPlugin21.audio.track = 2;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // show Exception here by messageBox or other
                    //if there are exceptions, the file has only one track
                }

            }

                else
                    axVLCPlugin21.audio.track = 1;            
        }
```

I hope to help you.